# Column 'column' cannot be null

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

im making a little web app. In this app i can register new Users. 
An User has one rol, and a rol can have many users.

Users table

[image]

Roles Table

[image]

If i make an INSERT i want the column rol_id to be "1" (rol: users). 
Everything works well in i work with the DBMS but it doesn't when i work with Spring because i get the following error

```
2018-05-01 11:00:43.432 ERROR 9448 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'rol_id' cannot be null
```

My code is this:

***Rol table***

```
@Entity
@Table(name="roles")
public class Rol implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_rol", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="rol")
    @NotEmpty
    private String rolType;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy= "rol")
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getRol() {
        return rolType;
    }

    public void setRol(String rol) {
        this.rolType = rol;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

}
```

***User table***

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_user", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="name")
    @NotEmpty
    @Length(min= 3, max= 25)
    private String name;

    @Column(name="surname")
    @NotEmpty
    @Length(min= 2, max=30)
    private String surname;

    @Column(name="email")
    @NotEmpty
    @Email
    @Length(min=5, max=30)
    private String email;

    @Column(name="birthdate", nullable = true)
    private String birthdate;

    @Column(name="created_at")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date createdAt = new Date();

    @Column(name="gender")
    @NotEmpty
    @Length(min=4, max=6)
    private String gender;

    @Column(name="username")
    @NotEmpty
    @Length(min=3, max=20)
    private String username;

    @Column(name="pass")
    @NotEmpty
    @Length(min=8, max=30)
    private String password;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="rol_id")
    private Rol rol;


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getBirthdate() {
        return birthdate;
    }

    public void setBirthdate(String birthdate) {
        this.birthdate = birthdate;
    }

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    /* MODOFIQUE ESTO ACA, NO SE SI ESTA BIEN */
    public String getRol() {
        return rol.getRol();
    }

    public void setRol(Rol rol) {
        this.rol = rol;
    }

}
```

***DAO Class***

```
public interface IUserDAO extends CrudRepository<User, Long>{
}
```

***UserService Interface***

```
public interface IUserService {

    public List<User> findAll();
    public void save(User user);
    public User findOne(Long id);

}
```

***Class who implements UserService***

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements IUserService{

    @Autowired
    IUserDAO userDAO;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<User> findAll() {
        return userDAO.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void save(User user) {
        userDAO.save(user);

    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public User findOne(Long id) {
        return userDAO.findOne(id);
    }

}
```

***This is my controller***

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("user")
public class UserController {

    Constants c = new Constants();

    @Autowired
    IUserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value= "user/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addUser(Model model) {
        User user = new User();
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        model.addAttribute(c.TITLE, "Add User");
        model.addAttribute(c.ADD_USER);
        return "user-add";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value= "user/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult result, Model model, RedirectAttributes ra, SessionStatus status) {
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return "redirect:/user/add";
        }

        try {
            userService.save(user);
            status.setComplete();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return "redirect:/user/list";
        }
        return "user-add";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value= "user/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listUsers(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("users", userService.findAll());
        model.addAttribute(c.TITLE, "Users List");
        model.addAttribute(c.LIST_USER);
        return "user-list";
    }

}
```

***And my view with thymeleaf***

```
<form th:action="@{/user/add}" method="POST" th:object="${user}" style="width: 70%;">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputName" class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" th:field="*{name}" autocomplete="off">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputSurname" class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Surname</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSurname" th:field="*{surname}" autocomplete="off">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail" class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" th:field="*{email}" autocomplete="off">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputBirthdate" class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Birthdate</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" id="inputBirthdate" th:field="*{birthdate}" autocomplete="off">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group mb-5">
        <label for="inputGender" class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Gender</label>
        <select type="date" class="form-control" id="inputGender" th:field="*{gender}">
            <option th:value="other">Other</option>
            <option th:value="male">Male</option>
            <option th:value="female">Female</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputUsername" class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUsername" th:field="*{username}" autocomplete="off">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword" class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" th:field="*{password}" autocomplete="off">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100">
        Add User
    </button>
</form>
```

All i want i set to 1 the rol_id when i make an Insert. 
For some reason only works in the DBMS but not in Spring.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should did it in that way: 1: Create the new Rol (in empty table it will have ID = 1) or load the Rol with ID = 1. 2: Set this Rol to the user (user.setRol(rol)) and save the user.

Comment: I already have 2 roles in my table.

Comment: Could you please show us how you're trying to create the `User`?

Comment: @crizzis what do you mean? I added more of my code.

Comment: Have you a Rol DAO/Service? Each user will have Rol with ID = 1?

Comment: Inside `UserController.save`, you simply call `userService.save(user)`. Is `user.rol` even populated at that point? The column `rol_id` is configured to be non-nullable, which implies you cannot leave `user.rol` empty

Comment: I don't. Because i dont need to save/edit roles. All i need is set to 1 the rol_id column in Users when i make an Insert

Comment: I don't think I follow. How are you planning to populate `rol_id` without setting `user.rol` to a non-null value? This is JPA, you don't handle join columns and tables directly, you establish associations between objects instead

Comment: @crizzis i Think is not populated. Anyway i added modified my Rol class to that *private Long id = (long)1;* but i keep gettin the same error

Comment: Yes because you anywhere creating a new Rol so the Rol object is empty and the rol_id is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I follow. How are you planning to populate `rol_id` without setting `user.rol` to a non-null value? This is JPA, you don't handle join columns and tables directly, you establish associations between objects instead.

If you want the newly created users to have the role with `id=1` assigned by default, you should modify your service accordingly:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void save(User user) {
    user.setRol(roleDao.getOne(1l));
    userDAO.save(user);
}
```